# Maclaurin series and expressing as a ln(argument)

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Found this question in my old homework notes that I did not do at the time! I always wondered how I do this... The first part is a explanation. It is kind of long. Sorry! 
[image]

***Here is the actual question guys!****
[image]

Back then, I lost 10 points for not even doing this question :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Even part: $$
\frac12\left(\ln(1+x)+\ln(1-x)\right) =\frac12\ln(1-x^2) = \ln \sqrt{ 1-x^2 }
$$
Odd part:  $$
\frac12\left(\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)\right) =\frac12\ln \left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)
=\ln \sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}
$$
The second one is actually a useful formula: as $x$ runs through the interval $(-1,1)$, the  values of $u=\frac{1+x}{1-x}$ run through all real numbers. Thus, one can get $\ln u$ using the power series for $\ln (1\pm x)$, which converge   for $-1<x<1$.

---

If you posted your own answer instead, I would upvote it, thus giving you those 10 points back...